# Karma public api lacks configFile option

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, karma-runner, gulp

gulp-karma suggests an external config file like this:

```
module.exports = {
    basePath: '',
    singleRun: true
};
```

I want an external config file like this (grunt-karma style):

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
         basePath: '',
         singleRun: true
    });
};
```

How to use the `proper config file` with karma API.

#### Details:

I am using gulp-karma, and as mentioned 
[there](https://github.com/karma-runner/gulp-karma/blob/master/gulpfile.js),
 i have to implement it on my own.

[Karma API](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/master/docs/dev/04-public-api.md) is very simple:

```
var server = require('karma').server;
server.start(config, done);
```

`config` variable is vague. It is a plain object with [configuration](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html):

```
var config = {
    basePath: '',
    singleRun: true
    // ...
}
```

Let's take a look at grunt-karma:

Sample grunt-karma config:

```
karma: {
  unit: {
      configFile: 'karma.conf.js'
  }
}
```

grunt-karma configuration can take a `configFile` option, which is not documented [anywhere](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html).

I can see, i can pass a `configFile` option from [karma source code](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/master/lib/server.js#L282):

`var config = cfg.parseConfig(cliOptions.configFile, cliOptions);`

Is there a documentation for the Karma API that mentions `configFile` option, how does grunt-karma know to 
[use it](https://github.com/karma-runner/grunt-karma/blob/master/tasks/grunt-karma.js#L56).

Comment: Please change your title to something more descriptive and useful to Google searchers.

Comment: Uhh... You just want the Karma documentation? (http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html) Slightly confused... Why not Google it?

Comment: @CaseyFalk Like i didn't read it... Why not read details?

Comment: @RoberyHarvey that's the best i could come up with, you can edit to something better.

Comment: Your question says, "Is there a documentation for [the configuration file]..." and I just gave you a link to the documentation. **What is your question?**

Comment: @CaseyFalk it doesn't mention `configFile` option, "Is there a documentation for `configFile` option". Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @CaseyFalk, and i am not complaining about the karma configuration file documentation, it's the public api documentation.

Comment: Then could you **clarify your question please? It is confusing** and you will receive more help if people don't struggle to comprehend your problem. :)

Answer (score 8):

This question is surprisingly relevant, and most of these comments breeze over the actual question posed at the end of this post: "How does grunt-karma know to use a config object with a property called `configFile`.

I, too, have been wondering the same thing as that property is not listed anywhere in the karma config docs. For instance, if I would like to run my karma tests via the public API in my gulpfile. It would look like this: 
...

```
var karmaConfig = require('spec/karma.conf.js');
// where my config file exports an object with properties like exclude:, path:
karma.start(karmaConfig)}, process.exit);
```

This would work fine, except if I wanted to export the config function so I can use the config constants (outlined [here](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/configuration-file.html)):

```
// allows me to do this

module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO
    });
}
```

But there's no way to get this to work unless you use something like this:

```
karma.start({configFile: 'spec/karma.conf.js'}, process.exit);
```

Where I simply pass in an object with a property `configFile` that points to the actual config file.

Karma docs **don't mention this anywhere** (as of this comment), but it's the only way to accomplish running my test via the API while using the config function export method.

Comment: @jbielick your answer is totally fine - it is not that easy to illustrate all of those different possibilitis as part of https://github.com/karma-runner/gulp-karma - but if you've got any ideas on how to make the example in https://github.com/karma-runner/gulp-karma better - pull request are welcomed!

Comment: @pzolowski.opensource Good call! That's the exact repo I used as a reference to get going and figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: @jbielick,I've this use case where I've to give the developer option to over ride/smart merge the karma config(which sits in a node module).For that I want to use `karma.start(configObj)`(without setting a configObj.configFile which I could do by just exporting a function with a configObj).You said in your answer "so I can use the config constants (outlined here)".Wouldn't I be able to use them even if I just pass a configObj instead of a path to karma config that exports a func?Karma server code anyway [sets the configObj](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/master/lib/config.js#L374)

Comment: @glad-s-river the code you liked to merges a variable called `cliOptions`, the options set via command line flags, I presume.