# How to include .istanbul.yml when running via Karma public API

Tags: karma-runner, configuration-files, istanbul, karma-coverage

I start Karma with, basically, `node wrapper.js`. That wrapper sets up the configuration including calling [`karma-coverage`](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage), starting Karma with `require('karma').runner.run`. `karma-coverage` calls out to Istanbul. (phew!)

I'd like to configure Istanbul with an `.istanbul.yml` file, mostly because I want to change the 'reporting watermarks'. Here's what my file looks like.

```
reporting:
  watermarks:
    statements: [90, 97]
    lines: [90, 97]
    functions: [90, 97]
    branches: [90, 97]
```

That looks correct, from what I've seen. But.. **it doesn't work**. I assume the problem is that istanbul doesn't know the current working directory or somehow this needs to be specified through `karma-coverage`.

If it helps, my Karma `config.basePath` is simply `''`.

I've attempted to find discussion of this specific problem. Sadly, [this question is the closest to my problem, but it's a FAQ entry about "how to name the file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537622/istanbul-yml-not-being-picked-up-by-istanbul). Here's [a question/answer discussing this in Grunt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871069/karma-public-api-lacks-configfile-option), but I wasn't able to extract anything useful.

I also trawled through the karma-runner issues on github, both open and closed. Looking at the source to karma-runner and combining it [with this issue from Istanbul](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/116#issuecomment-31323913), I assume it's not possible [because of this line](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage/blob/c503499d276533e4a53c6eb1b2c68c36e8250000/lib/reporter.js#L136). Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Go to the `istanbul` directory within the `karma-coverage` module:

  ```
  cd node_modules/karma-coverage/node_modules/istanbul
  ```
- Go to the `lib` directory:

  ```
  cd lib
  ```
- Add the `.istanbul.yml` file there

The `config.js` script in the `lib` directory finds the path to the `.istanbul.yml` file via the following line:

```
 path.resolve('.istanbul.yml')
```

That's it.

The `path.resolve` method works as follows:

> If after using all from paths still no absolute path is found, the current working directory is used as well. The resulting path is normalized, and trailing slashes are removed unless the path gets resolved to the root directory.

**References**

- [node.js Path Module: Resolve method](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_from_to)
- [istanbul config.js: .istanbul.yml path](http://gotwarlost.github.io/istanbul/public/apidocs/files/lib_config.js.html#l378)
- [How do you force the absolute path for node modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669390/1113772)
- [People complaining about strange coverage reports](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage/issues/45)
- [.istanbul.yml work with gulp-istanbul?](https://github.com/SBoudrias/gulp-istanbul/issues/56)

Comment: I did not see istanbul inside of the karma coverage anywhere.